# String to say when a call is made using Twilio in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, twilio, call, twilio-twiml

I am using Twilio of version 8.0.0 in spark-shell.

Code:

```
val accountSid = "<Your Twilio Account SID>"
val authToken = "<Your Twilio Auth Token>"
val str="Hello from zainab"
Twilio.init(accountSid, authToken)
val helloTwiml = new VoiceResponse.Builder()
  .say(new Say.Builder(str)
  .voice(Say.Voice.POLLY_MATTHEW).build())
  .build().toXml()
val toPhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber("<TO - your cellphone number>")
val fromPhoneNumber = new PhoneNumber("<FROM - your Twilio number>")
val call = Call.creator(toPhoneNumber, fromPhoneNumber, helloTwiml).create()
```

Expected to say whatever is in the string str.

Error:

```
<console>:42: error: overloaded method value creator with alternatives:
(x$1: com.twilio.type.Endpoint,x$2: com.twilio.type.Endpoint,x$3: S 
tring)com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.CallCreator <and>
(x$1: com.twilio.type.Endpoint,x$2: com.twilio.type.Endpoint,x$3: 
com.twilio.type.Twiml)com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.CallCreator <and>
(x$1: com.twilio.type.Endpoint,x$2: com.twilio.type.Endpoint,x$3: 
java.net.URI)com.twilio.rest.api.v2010.account.CallCreator
cannot be applied to (com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber, com.twilio.type.PhoneNumber, 
com.twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse.Builder)
val call = Call.creator(toPhoneNumber, fromPhoneNumber, helloTwiml).create()
                   ^
```

please let me know where correction is needed or any other way to make this happen.

Comment: The error says that this method `creator` does not accept these parameters. Have you looked at the documentation? Which method are you expecting to use?